# Should I start looking for a new job? If so, how soon?

Tags: new-job, united-kingdom, first-job

I'm an 18 year old Software Development apprentice in the UK and my apprenticeship finishes soon (2 months). At the end of this there is a high chance that the company I work for will renew my 1 year contract to a permanent position, but this is not guaranteed. Should I keep my options open and apply for other jobs and if I should, how soon should I start?

Note: I've never looked or applied for a job before in my life, this is my first ever job and I was approached by the company, hence why I'm unsure on what the norm is, (if there is one).

Comment: Apply for other jobs regardless. You need the interviewing experience for long-term employment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I keep my options open and apply for other jobs and if I
>   should, how soon should I start?

It's always good to have as many options as possible. To ensure that, you should look for other jobs while you are waiting to hear about your renewable.

Two months before you need a job isn't too early to start looking. Depending on your locale and the economy, it could take far longer than that to find the right job.

Best case, you find a great job and at the same time you get a great renewal offer. You'll have a choice between two good outcomes.